# Calculate the average of nested cells

Tags: matlab, loops, cell-array

Suppose that we have this cell array:

```
data = {{[1,2,3],[3,6,3]},{[6,8,2],[1,1,1]},{[4,8,3],[1,2,3]},{[5,1,3],[1,0,2]}};
```

we have four main cells and in every cell we have two cells. I want average between four main cells like this:

```
Average 1 between:
1   2   3
6   8   2
4   8   3
5   1   3
---------
4   4.75   2.75

Average 2 between:
3   6   3
1   1   1
1   2   3
1   0   2
---------
1.5  2.25  2.25
```

Finally, we should gather these two results in a cell array. What is the fastest way to do this, with minimum number of loops?

Comment: Why do you have cells and not matrices? 3D matrices would be your friend here.

Comment: @adriaan.. Currently I'm storing my results in `data`. Any better way to do that? Add your answer :-)

Comment: Yes, store them in 3D matrices. I can't add an answer, as I have no idea how you create your data.

Comment: @RCaetano you edited a 1x4 cell to look like a 4x1 cell. That's not the same. Please refrain from editing code which destroys the original purpose.

Comment: I did not notice that @Adriaan :/ Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow Adriaan's advise, but:

```
x = reshape([data{:}],2,[])';
means = reshape(mean(cell2mat(x)),[],2)'    
means =    
    4.0000    4.7500    2.7500
    1.5000    2.2500    2.2500
```